# How to prove the existence of eigenvalues of T if X is an infinite-dimensional space, where T is an operator on X?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, spectral-theory

For finite-dimensional space X, we know any operator T on X can be seen as a matrix. From there we can give the existence of eigenvalues through the fundamental theorem of algebra. The set of all eigenvalues will be the spectrum of T. Clearly it is a compact set and its complement in the complex plane is the resolvent set of T. If I am wrong anywhere then please correct me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Eigen values need not exist in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: For an example of an bounded operator without any eigenvalue just looke [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716280/does-every-bounded-operator-on-a-complex-hilbert-space-have-an-eigenvalue)

Comment: We always assume that $X$ is a Banach space. The set of eigenvalues is not the spectrum. $\lambda$ being in the spectrum means that $T-\lambda Id$ is not invertible, that's it. That does not imply that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue: In the infinite-dimensional case, non-surjective linear maps can still be injective. If $T$ is a so called compact operator, then the spectrum will be non-empty. Yes the spectrum is compact.